# Rails On Create undefined method `destroyed?' for #<Array:0x007feeff8abf88>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When trying to create a record, I get the error "undefined method destroyed?" right at the point "if @form_response.save" and I'm not sure why. Here is the controller:

```
class FormResponsesController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!
before_action :initialize_form, only: [:new]

def index
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @forms = Form.all
end

def new

end

def create
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @form = Form.find(params[:form_id])
    @form_response = FormResponse.new(form_response_params)
    @form_response.patient = @patient
    @form_response.form = @form
    if @form_response.save
        flash[:success] = "Form filled out."
        redirect_to patient_forms_path
    else
        puts("Wasn't created")
        flash[:error] = @form_response.errors.full_messages.to_sentence
        # THIS ISN'T WORKING, FIX THIS
        redirect_to new_patient_form_response_path(id: params[:form_id])
    end
end

def show

end

def destroy
    @form_response = FormResponse.find(params[:id]).destroy
    flash[:success] = "Form Response Deleted."
    redirect_to patient_forms_path, notice: "Form Response Deleted."
end

private

def initialize_form
    puts("initialize_form")
    @patient = Patient.find(params[:patient_id])
    @form = Form.find(params[:id])
    @form_response = FormResponse.new()

    @form.form_sections.each_with_index do |section, index|
        @form_response.form_response_sections.build(
            form_section: section
        )
        section.form_fields.each do |field|
            @form_response.form_response_sections[index].form_response_fields.build(
                field_type: field.field_type,
                name: field.name,
                key: field.key,
                field_width: field.field_width,
                value: field.value,
                description: field.description,
                required: field.required,
                form_field: field
            )
        end
    end
end

def form_response_params
    params.require("form_response").permit(
        form_response_sections_attributes: [
            :form_section_id,
            form_response_fields_attributes: [
                :form_field_id, 
                :key, 
                :value
            ]
        ]
    )
end
```

end

FormResponse Model:

```
class FormResponse < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :patient
    belongs_to :form

    has_many :form_response_sections
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_response_sections
end
```

FormResponseSection Model

```
class FormResponseSection < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :form_response_fields
    belongs_to :form_section
    has_many :form_response_fields
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :form_response_fields
end
```

FormResponseField Model

```
class FormResponseField < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :form_response_section
    belongs_to :form_field
end
```

As you can see, there's two nested attributes, trying to understand what could be going wrong... "since destroyed?" shouldn't be running at this point because it doesn't exist. Here is the console output when you submit the new method:

```
 pp/controllers/form_responses_controller.rb:20:in `create'
::1 - - [24/May/2018:15:20:39 PDT] "POST /patients/1/form_responses HTTP/1.1" 500 192571
http://localhost:3000/patients/1/form_responses/new?id=1 -> /patients/1/form_responses
Started POST "/patients/1/form_responses" for ::1 at 2018-05-24 15:20:41 -0700
Processing by FormResponsesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"zN9OLKcZRE9li1j019Mp1qkvWI8aYqhxbV2YRgPdnfNnJcAqivNtuPjxK6Vm210lGUNGuwoBFcQObRyUVebgWQ==", "form_id"=>"1", "form_response"=>{"form_response_sections_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"form_section_id"=>"1", "form_response_fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"form_field_id"=>"1", "value"=>""}, "1"=>{"form_field_id"=>"2", "value"=>""}, "2"=>{"form_field_id"=>"3", "value"=>""}, "3"=>{"form_field_id"=>"4", "value"=>""}, "4"=>{"form_field_id"=>"5", "value"=>""}, "5"=>{"form_field_id"=>"6", "value"=>""}}}, "1"=>{"form_section_id"=>"2", "form_response_fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"form_field_id"=>"7", "value"=>"0"}, "1"=>{"form_field_id"=>"8", "value"=>"0"}}}, "2"=>{"form_section_id"=>"3", "form_response_fields_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"form_field_id"=>"9", "value"=>"0"}}}}}, "commit"=>"Submit", "patient_id"=>"1"}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Patient Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "patients".* FROM "patients" WHERE "patients"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Form Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "forms".* FROM "forms" WHERE "forms"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  FormSection Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "form_sections".* FROM "form_sections" WHERE "form_sections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 4], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 5], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormSection Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "form_sections".* FROM "form_sections" WHERE "form_sections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 2], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 7], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 8], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormSection Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "form_sections".* FROM "form_sections" WHERE "form_sections"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  FormField Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "form_fields".* FROM "form_fields" WHERE "form_fields"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 9], ["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.1ms)  rollback transaction
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "form_responses" ("form_id", "patient_id") VALUES (?, ?)  [["form_id", 1], ["patient_id", 1]]
   (2.2ms)  rollback transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 33ms (ActiveRecord: 3.9ms)



NoMethodError (undefined method `destroyed?' for #<Array:0x007feeff8abf88>):

app/controllers/form_responses_controller.rb:20:in `create'
::1 - - [24/May/2018:15:20:41 PDT] "POST /patients/1/form_responses HTTP/1.1" 500 192571
http://localhost:3000/patients/1/form_responses/new?id=1 -> /patients/1/form_responses
```

Comment: Which Rails version are you using?

Comment: 5.1.4 is the version I'm using

Comment: We can't really help without seeing the contents of your FormResponse model and a complete backtrace for the exception. Please edit these into your question.

Comment: I added the FormResponse models, I'm not sure what you mean by "complete backtrace for the exception". The console log shows everything

Comment: In your FormResponseSection model, the first `belongs_to :form_response_fields` should be `belongs_to :form_response`